# NSTask in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sh, nstask

So I'm trying to run some terminal commands from my program, and I am getting some confusing errors.

Im a newer developer coming from Java, so I may be missing something.

Heres the code:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSString *commitText = [commitMessage stringValue];
NSString *a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cd %@", dirPath];
NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"git commit -m '%@'", commitText];
NSArray *commands = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:a,
                     @"git add 'Project'",
                     c,
                     @"git push origin HEAD",
                     nil];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];

// Do commands
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:commands,
                 nil];

[task setArguments: args];
[task launch];
```

And here are the errors:

```
2012-06-09 08:35:20.561 Auto Git[5433:403] -[__NSArrayI fileSystemRepresentation]:                 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb250d6a1e0
2012-06-09 08:35:20.561 Auto Git[5433:403] -[__NSArrayI fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb250d6a1e0
2012-06-09 08:35:20.679 Auto Git[5433:403] (
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870b4f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90e35d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff871411be -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
  3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870a1e23 ___forwarding___ + 371
  4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870a1c38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
  5   Foundation                          0x00007fff9174f3a3 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 901
  6   Auto Git                            0x000000010d83c6db -[Push push:] + 571
  7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff870a470d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f8f7e -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f8eb2 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 88
  10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f8ddd -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 137
  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f82a0 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2014
  12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e177fc4 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 489
  13  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0f6eaa -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e0c2348 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6306
  15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e05ba55 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
  16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8dff20c6 -[NSApplication run] + 555
  17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8e26e244 NSApplicationMain + 867
  18  Auto Git                            0x000000010d83bff2 main + 34
  19  Auto Git                            0x000000010d83bfc4 start + 52
  20  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
 )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments array contains an array. It should be an array of strings. Use your `commands` object as that parameter for NSTask.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your passing a array with a array of strings to `setArguments`. You should pass an array with strings only not an nested array.

But I think you misunderstand how the arguments to `NSTask` works. You should probably do something like this:

```
[task setArguments:[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     @"git", @"add", @"Project", nil]
                    autorelease]];
```

Etc, or if you really want to use `sh` you probably need to add some `;` to separate the shell commands.

Comment: Thank you. I am also having a problem with the "cd %@", dirPath  because it says there is no such dir Example /bin/sh: cd /Users/webstreet/Documents/GIT/findmycar: No such file or directory

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `-c` options to `sh` also?

Comment: I dont quite know I'm new to sh

Comment: Ok. I think you should read about `-c` in the [man page for sh](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sh.1.html). Try in a interactive shell if you want to test how it behaves. Hint: `sh -c echo test` wont work but `sh -c "echo test"` will. But I think a more robust solution in your case is to execute each command as separate `NSTask` `launch`:s. Another solution is to include a helper shell script with your application that takes the `dirPath` and `commitText` as arguments and performs the commands and then launch one `NSTask` to run it.